# webkit backdrop filter works after zooming in

Tags: css, safari

Im using a backdrop filter to blur and saturate a part of my page, this works great. Except on the iPhone where it only appears after i zoom in on the element. I have no idea why this happens.

This is the css:

-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px) saturate(180%);
  backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);

Comment: Same problem, similar CSS. So far no clue what's happening. After zooming in I can zoom out again and the blur still works. Might hint at this being an iOS bug.

After refreshing the page, it's gone again.

(moved from answers to comments - picked wrong section on my phone accidentally)